# Modify working update/insert to do it in batches of 1000

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I currently have PDO statements performing updates and inserts according to conditions, and it's working perfectly but I'd like to modify it to do this in batches since we're getting more data now.

I was  hoping to do this in batches of 500 or 1000 but I'm not sure how I would incorporate that into preparing and executing PDO statements.

Any help or guidance here is much appreciated.

Here is the code for these functions:

```
//Create prepared INSERT statement
$insertPlacement = "
    INSERT ignore INTO placements_new (sku_id, group_id, dealer_id, start_date, expire_date, locations, order_num)
    SELECT 
        id, 
        sku_group_id, 
        :DEALER, 
        DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT(:SHIPDATE, CHAR(20)), '%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 7 DAY) as start_date,
        DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT(:SHIPDATE, CHAR(20)), '%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 127 DAY) as expire_date, 
        :QUANTITY,
        :INVOICE  
    FROM skus s  
    WHERE  s.frame=:FRAME AND s.cover1=:COVER AND s.color1=:COLOR
";

//create update statement for necessary constraints
$updatePlacement = "
    UPDATE placements_new 
    SET expire_date = DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT(current_date(), CHAR(20)), '%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 127 DAY)
";

while ($row2 = $detailCheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $values = [
        ":DEALER" => $row2["DEALER"],
        ":SHIPDATE" => $row2["SHIPDATE"],
        ":QUANTITY" => $row2["QUANTITY"],
        ":INVOICE" => $row2["INVOICE"],
        ":FRAME" => $row2["FRAME"],
        ":COVER" => $row2["COVER"],
        ":COLOR" => $row2["COLOR"],
    ];

    $values2 = [
        ":DEALER" => $row2["DEALER"],
        ":FRAME" => $row2["FRAME"],
        ":COVER" => $row2["COVER"],
        ":COLOR" => $row2["COLOR"],
        ":INVOICE" => $row2["INVOICE"],

    ];

    try{
        //Array will contain records that are expired
        $checkExisting = $MysqlConn->prepare($expiredCheck);
        $existingRslt = $checkExisting->execute($values2);
        $count3 = $checkExisting->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        //Array will contain records that are valid
        $checkExistingValid = $MysqlConn->prepare($validCheck);
        $existingVldRslt = $checkExistingValid->execute($values2);
        $count4 = $checkExistingValid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        //print_r($count3);

    }catch(PDOException $ex){
            echo "QUERY FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
    }



    // IF records do not exist, or records exist and today is after expiration date
    if(empty($count3) && empty($count4)){
        for($i=0; $i<$row2["QUANTITY"]; $i++) {  
            try{
                $insert = $MysqlConn->prepare($insertPlacement);
                $insertRslt = $insert->execute($values);
            }catch(PDOException $ex){
                echo "QUERY FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
            }

        }
    }elseif(!empty($count3)){
        for($i=0; $i<$row2['QUANTITY']; $i++){
            try{
                $insert = $MysqlConn->prepare($insertPlacement);
                $insertRslt = $insert->execute($values);
            }catch(PDOException $ex){
                echo "QUERY FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }elseif(!empty($count4)){
        for($i=0; $i<$row2['QUANTITY']; $i++){
            try{
                $update = $MysqlConn->prepare($updatePlacement);
                $updateRslt = $update->execute($values);
            }catch(PDOException $ex){
                echo "QUERY FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }else{
        die("No action taken");
    }
```

Comment: Can you not use LIMIT on the SELECT?

Comment: True, I can. I wasn't sure if that would be the fastest/most accurate and thought I might need to use a batch operation but that may be the best after all

Comment: My only issue with that is I'll have to run the script multiple times to get it up to date right?

Comment: Well...you could do it all in one script execution. Count the number of records / 1000 and that will tell you how many loop iterations or batches you need. Alternatively you could run the script multiple times until the batches were completed. You would have to flush the origin table of the INSERTED items or track which batch was last successful. Are you having performance issues? I would do it as a single SELECT INSERT until is becomes necessary to actually batch the INSERT's

Comment: That makes sense actually. No performance issues, just trying to cover my bases in advance. I do appreciate the ideas though1